# How do I have nests with nests (Elastic Search Mapping)

Tags: json, python-3.x, elasticsearch, relationship

I want to map the json below with Elastic Search Mapping:

JSON:

```
{"user_id":{
    "data_flow_id_1":[
        {"file_location": "C:/ewew","timestamp": "2019-01-01T00:00:00"},
        {"file_location": "C:/ewew2", "timestamp": "2019-02-01T00:00:00"}
            ],

    "data_flow_id_2":[
        {"file_location": "C:/ewew3","timestamp": "2019-03-01T00:00:00"},
        {"file_location": "C:/ewew4", "timestamp": "2019-04-01T00:00:00"}
            ]
}}
```

so the "user_id" 'owns' multiple dataflow_ids which have their own locations.
I have this so far, but it doesn't model exactly what that json describes -

ES MAPPING:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "dataflow_type": {
        "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
              "user_id": {"type": "string"},
              "data_flow_id": {"type": "string"},
              "file_location": {"type":"string"},
              "timestamp": {"type":"date"}
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm struggling to nest the dataflow_id_* bit in the user_id - will I need a nest in another nest?

UPDATE: 
something like this maybe?

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "user_id": {
        "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
              "data_flow_id":{
                 "type": "nested",
                    "properties": 
                    {       "file_location": {"type": "text"},
                            "timestamp": {"type":"date"}
                    }
          }
      }
     }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to exactly model it to the json structure? This will result in too much of nesting which should be avoided. You first approach is better. In that too you can avoid the only nested field.

Comment: The JSON is there just as a visual aid, I'm not actually modeling JSON, but I need a way to have a user_id that holds multiple data_flow_ids and their file locations. So i figured nesting would help keep that relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use the mapping below in order to avoid too much of nesting.

```
PUT myindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "user_id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "data_flow_id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "file_location": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "timestamp": {
        "type": "date"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You have to then index documents as below

```
PUT myindex/_doc/1
{
  "user_id": "some_id",
  "data_flow_id": "data_flow_id_1",
  "file_location": "C:/ewew",
  "timestamp": "2019-01-01T00:00:00"
}
```

Similarly other documents can be added as:

```
PUT myindex/_doc/2
{"user_id":"some_id","data_flow_id":"data_flow_id_1","file_location":"C:/ewew2","timestamp":"2019-02-01T00:00:00"}

PUT myindex/_doc/3
{"user_id":"some_id","data_flow_id":"data_flow_id_2","file_location":"C:/ewew3","timestamp":"2019-03-01T00:00:00"}

PUT myindex/_doc/4
{"user_id":"some_id","data_flow_id":"data_flow_id_2","file_location":"C:/ewew4","timestamp":"2019-04-01T00:00:00"}
```

The disadvantage of the above approach will be that instead of 2 documents you have to index 4 document for the JSON you mentioned in the question. But this will result in the search queries to be simple. Nesting on the other hand can result into complex queries.

**Sample query to get docs where `data_flow_id` is `data_flow_id_1`**

```
POST myindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "data_flow_id": "data_flow_id_1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this information, could you please provide a sample search query?

Comment: This is great, thank you, when you get time, can you please provide just a basic summary of what its actually doing?

Comment: Added sample query. Feel free to upvote as well. Let me know for which part you need explaination.

Comment: I wish I could upvote - I'm a noob, not got enough rep :P. - just a summary of the mapping would be greatly appreciated